# JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'function'

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have a collection that contains BsonJavascript object.

```
{ 
    "Name" : "HourlyMP", 
    "MapFunction" : function(){
        var _id = this.srcip + " - " + this.hour
        var valueData = {
            ip: this.srcip,
            session: 1
        }
        emit(_id, valueData);
    } 
}
```

As you see the value of "MapFunction" field is BsonJavascript. I can Export and Import this data successfully. But when I Deserialize exported json into BsonDocument i get this error:

```
JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'function'
```

By the way i am using official C# 2.2 driver and my deserialize code is below:

```
BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(myjsonstring)
```

**Edit**

I defined function as string then converted it to BsonJavascriptFunction inside my code. This solved my problem. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, [`BsonSerializer.Deserialize<TNominalType>(String)`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.2/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization_BsonSerializer_Deserialize__1_5.htm) deserializes a **JSON** string.

Functions aren't valid in JSON.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201705/mongo-c-sharp-json-reader-was-expecting-a-value-but-found-replsetgetstatus